# Use matrix c\c++ API with row-based indexing

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix

in my project I perform some calculations in `CUDA\c++`, and then I use Matrix API from Matlab (`mxCreateNumericArray`) to save my array as matrix into `.mat` file. In `c++` I work with native row-based indexing, however `Matlab` functions assume column-based order. Is there a way to quickly fix this? I can convert row-based to column based, but don't want to do this (for greater performance).  Here is a piece of c++ code (with 3x3 simple array):

```
float data[9] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 };
MATFile *pmat;
const char *file = "mattest.mat";
pmat = matOpen(file, "w");
const mwSize dims[] = { 3, 3 };
mxArray *pa1 = mxCreateNumericArray(2, dims, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
memcpy((void *)(mxGetPr(pa1)), (void *)data, 3*3*sizeof(float));
matPutVariable(pmat, "LocalDouble", pa1);
mxDestroyArray(pa1);
```

So, Matrix here is

```
 a={1 2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9}
```

It is stored in array `data` (row-major order). But as a result, matrix in `mattest.mat` file is

```
 a={1 4 7
    2 5 8
    3 6 9}
```

For symmetric array quick transposition works. But my array is not symmetric and comparatively large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I see is to just use your code as it is, but transpose the matrix in MATLAB (basically transposing it is lazy-evaluated in MATLAB, it just changes the "view").

Otherwise, change the way you store the matrix in C++, and address the `(i,j)` element like `mat[i + j*nrows]`, this way you effectively write it in column-major order.

AFAIK, There is no other "direct" way of using `mx`-like functions and change from C/C++'s row-major order to column-major order.

Comment: This is correct. +1.  Another way (that I sometimes do) is to `malloc` up memory in my MEX code that is row-major, and I copy the elements over using column-major indexing so that the allocated memory becomes row major.  Once that's done, I use row-major indexing.  This allows me to use C/C++ code that was designed for row-major arrays to be interfaced with MATLAB.

Comment: @rayryeng nice trick, probably it is a bit faster than using pointer arithmetics

Comment: Thanks, yes. I didn't write that my matrix is not square. But I just discovered, that if I write (M1xM2) array stored in row-major order into (M2xM1) array in column-major, I can simply transpose it after.